# How start a script or command during the fedora startup

Tags: shell, fedora, iptables, boot

I try for two or three hours , to exec a command with a script during the boot of fedora 23.

I see some tutorials with chkconfig but on my fedora, i have only systemctl, chkconfig is too old no ?.

I try to create a service but even when i exec : `systemctl enable my_service` after the reboot , that does not exec my service. manually `systemctl start my_service` works.

But more weird it's that the service starts because when i write `systemctl list-unit-files –type=service` , i see my iptablesvpn.service enable . So really i don't understand why the command inside the script is not executed or maybe to soon, i don't know :/

So i trieda other solution which is to add a script in `/etc/init.d/script.sh` with a chmod +x on it. But even that does not work.

I just want to restore iptables after the reboot. So i want something like: `/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/firewall.rules`. After the boot, if i write this command in a terminal, that work and my vpn is happy but if don't write this command my vpn does not work.

So if you can help me to exec this command line , i will be happy because that seems to be very simple but it's not for me :/. Thank you

Comment: If you wnat to make yout script as service, you can read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot , but if you only wnat to run the command (in script) you can put your command in /etc/rc.d/rc.local.

Comment: ok i'll try this afternoon, so if i understand, i put my command about iptables-restore in the file /etc/rc.d/rc.local ? Also is it possible that the command about iptables is executed too early and in fact the service does not start yet so the command does not work ?

Comment: Yes, try put your command in the last line of this file, this way you have sure that will execute in last.

Comment: ok i tried but that does not work :/. The command that i write manually is `iptables -F` , maybe something wrong with my iptables :/. i'm lost but  `iptables -F` fix my problem manually, so the same during the boot should be fix also my problem isn't ?

Comment: Try /sbin/iptables -F, if you need disable iptables at boot: chkconfig iptables off

Comment: Why not use the existing system for saving firewall rules -- either firewalld or the iptables init scripts?

Comment: ok i refound all my iptables to be clean, but still the same problem ... but i found the problem that was so stupid , i wrote a bad script in `/etc/rc.local` yesterday, i totally forgot this file with all my tries ! thank you because with your method in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` , i fall up on the other file :)

Comment: @mattdm,  i dont know why but that does not work if i don't restart the service iptables... My command (today and now ) at boot is just `service iptables restart`. I use the iptables-save and also the sysconfig file to allow the load of iptables at boot. But still my problem until i restart the service iptables ... any idea. Sorry for the mess but now , my iptables are clean and save properly. :). Just this problem of restart necessary to work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my process which work even if it's not optimized with the script shell at the boot :

1) 
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state –state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -L -v

2) Edit /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config and put "yes" instead of "no" about iptables save options on Fedora stop and restart

3) Create a script shell in /etc/rc.d/rc.local where i write `service iptables restart` and it's good :)

You see something useless or weird in this process ?

Comment: Mhh solve not really, not yet but almost :). OK the initial question is solved , you're right. But  I don't want create a script to restart iptables service, it's weird i think. I write this text to help some people which are totally blocked and also in the goal that you understand my steps. But if someone can help me on the last problem , i take it :)